# sending message to slack channel using PHP/Guzzle prints "Array"

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm trying to post to a Slack channel but it's not working as intended.
The only message I get in Slack says Array, as in that the value of text is an Array. As I'm understanding their docs, it shouldn't do that. If I move the text to the first level of the array, the actual text is displayed, so I'm guessing that my request is working fine. What am I missing? This is being done in PHP with GuzzleHttpClient.

My message:

```
[
 'type' => 'section',
 'text' => [
      'type' => 'mrkdwn',
      'text' => 'This is supposed to be my text'
 ]
];
```

My request to the API:

```
$request = $client->post($url, [
        RequestOptions::JSON => $messages
    ]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems not as obvious, but you cannot use the message formatting used for their **API** `chat.postMessage` for incoming webhooks. Both have different formatting.

With that said, [follow this documentation for webhook messages](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) and it's respective formatting [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting).

What you were trying to do is use so called "blocks" which seems to be dedicated to their [API messaging](https://api.slack.com/messaging) instead.

If you try your message on this [message builder](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder) (which is intended for webhooks), it will fail. But it will work on [this message builder](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder).

Perhaps you can get away with using new-lines if you want your message to appear over multiple lines. See [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#multiline_messages).

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is incorrect, see documentation: https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/layouts#stack-of-blocks

It should be array of message blocks, you need to nest it further one time.

```
[
    [
        'type' => 'section',
        'text' => [
            'type' => 'mrkdwn',
            'text' => 'This is supposed to be my text'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: I've tried this but then I get an error response back: "`400 Bad Request` response: no_text"

I'm starting to think that you can't use their layout blocks with incoming webhooks :/

Comment: @DennisEk yeah, that seems to be the case sadly. I posted another answer. Depending on what you are trying to achieve with your message, you may or may not have to use their messaging API. It will be different workflow unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DennisEk No problem. Since you are new user to Stackoverflow, generally if you feel an answer has solved the problem, you mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As @ncla mentioned, if you are using "Block UI" elements, using the incoming webhook API, you cant send the blocks as with the `chat.postMessage`.

Its not obvious on the Blocks documentation, but in the 
[Messages payload page](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/payload) it specifies that you can send a `blocks` attribute. This will allow you to use the Blocks structure.

Comment: Thank you - very nice tip about using `'blocks' => [...]` rather than `'text' => [...]` It works when using the old-fashioned incoming webhook method.